# Embedding javascript variables within MVC razor syntax

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using ajax to fill a series of dropdown list in an MVC 3 razor environment and am trying to create a general function to do this. The core bit of the function I am having problems with is

```
url: '@Url.Action("SecondaryList")'
```

where I want to replace "SecondaryList" with a JavaScript variable.

So

```
var myUrl = 'SecondaryList'
url: '@Url.Action(' + myUrl + ')'
```

I have no idea how to do it as the above does not work!

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) javascript function. Start by declaring a javascript variable

```
var myUrl = 'SomeAction';
```

and then use a dummy placeholder with the server side Url.Action helper that you could replace with the javascript variable:

```
url: '@Url.Action("__url__")'.replace('__url__', myUrl)
```

Comment: Excellent answer - simple, elegant and _100%_ effective. (Also, obvious to me once seen). Many thanks.